# OpenGL 8 bit alpha texture format

Tags: opengl, format, textures

I have a greyscale 8-bit bitmap which I am going to use as a mask for font glyph rendering.  The bitmap pixels are just an alpha value.  I'm wondering whether it's better to convert this to RGBA, or whether I can use a format like GL_ALPHA8_EXT, which I cannot seem to find any documentation for anywhere, although I can see it in glext.h.

Is GL_ALPHA8_EXT widely supported?

Comment: What was wrong with regular 'ole `GL_ALPHA8`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `GL_ALPHA8` is supported, i'm using it on desktop and iOS. Actually i've never heard of `GL_ALPHA8_EXT` and a quick research shows that it is part of the [EXT_texture](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/ogl-sample/registry/EXT/texture.txt) extension which is supported by actually all graphic cards i know and should be the same like `GL_ALPHA8`.